# jQuery image thumbnail change on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a working jsFiddle attached. Yes, it works, however what I am trying to achieve seems beyond my experience.

At the moment it shows a row of thumbnails and when you click on one of these it will show the same image bigger as the featured image.

What I need to do is be able to show the thumbnails as a different image to what will appear as a featured image.

For example, I have a product featured image which will also have a zoomed in cropped version of this image to be the thumbnail.

Thumbnail 1 (zoomed in cropped version) / Featured Image 1

Thumbnail 2 (zoomed in cropped version) / Featured Image 2

Thumbnail 3 (zoomed in cropped version) / Featured Image 3

https://jsfiddle.net/gq74rgc3/2/

```
<img id="image" src="http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg" border="0" />

<img src="http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />
<img src="http://smartyvet.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/happy5.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />
<img src="http://www.telegram.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/a.aaa-Happy-animals.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".thumb").click(function () {
    var dir = $(this).attr("src");
    $('#image').hide();
    $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#image').attr("src", dir);
});
});
```

Does this make sense?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What you need is when you click the thumbnail appear a random image instead of the clicked thumbnail?

Comment: @Bak Not a random image but a related image to the thumbnail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to change an image on click and back again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811672/trying-to-change-an-image-on-click-and-back-again)

Comment: Do you have the thumbnail versions of your main image in a different folder to the feature image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a data tag to your thumbnail containing the url of the image you want to display on click then instead of getting the src of the img get the data attribute value.

see: https://jsfiddle.net/gq74rgc3/3/

```
<img data-big="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUM5JaTT3WP59hqqcL5pYEgcfyB4qUvzLFv4k5pzLqBeRsJaOi" src="http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thumb").click(function () {
        var dir = $(this).data("big");
        $('#image').hide();
        $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#image').attr("src", dir);
    });
});
```

Comment: To add onto this - are we able to integrate a border around the thumbnail on click with the first thumbnail being active? @Gregg Duncan

Comment: easily by creating a class .thumb.active { border: 1px solid red;} in your css. Then add the class the img tag that will be active when the page loads. Then remove active class from all .thumbs and add it back to the one clicked. https://jsfiddle.net/gq74rgc3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var images_array = ["http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg","http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg","http://smartyvet.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/happy5.jpg","http://www.telegram.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/a.aaa-Happy-animals.jpg"];
    $(".thumb").click(function () {
        var dir = $(this).attr("src");
        $('#image').hide();
        $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#image').attr("src", images_array[Math.floor((Math.random()*4))]);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xL3p0drv/1/

It takes a random index from the array and show the image